# How to list Parent & Child Category BY Knockoutjs

Tags: magento2, category, knockoutjs

I want to list category block By knockoutjs.
Currently I Implemented By Direct PHP Code But I want to do by Knockout js.

```
My Block code
----------
namespace QuickLearn\Knockout\Block;
class CategorisCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $_categoryHelper;
     protected $categoryFlatConfig;
     protected $topMenu;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState,
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topMenu
    ) {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
        $this->topMenu = $topMenu;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Return categories helper
     */   
    public function getCategoryHelper()
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper;
    }
    /**
     * Return top menu html
     * getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $limit = 0)
     * example getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', 0)
     */   
    public function getHtml()
    {
        return $this->topMenu->getHtml();
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve current store categories
     *
     * @param bool|string $sorted
     * @param bool $asCollection
     * @param bool $toLoad
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Collection|array
     */    
   public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve child store categories
     *
     */ 
    public function getChildCategories($category)
    {
           if ($this->categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource()) {
                $subcategories = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
            } else {
                $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
            }
            return $subcategories;
    }
}


My Phtml
------------

<?php
$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);

$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($categories as $category):
    print_r($categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category));
     if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        continue;
     }
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a></li>
<?php  
if($childrenCategories = $this->getChildCategories($category)):
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($childrenCategories as $childrenCategory):
     if (!$childrenCategory->getIsActive()) {
        continue;
     }
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($childrenCategory) ?>"><?php echo $childrenCategory->getName() ?></a></li>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
<?php
endif;
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

I want to know that how can i implement this by Knockoutjs.